# C# Oakton flags vs arguments

Tags: c#, command-line-interface

In case anyone comes across this and could not find a solution, here is what I found:

I have added a new `Oakton` command and 3 flags.

The issue is that two of them are being recognized as flags while the other one is recognized as an argument.

Code:

```
[FlagAlias("o", true)]
[Description("Flag One")]
[Required]
public string OneFlag { get; set; }

[FlagAlias("t", true)]
[Description("Flag Two")]
[Required]
public string TwoFlag { get; set; }

[FlagAlias("r", true)]
[Description("Flag Three")]
[Required]
public string Three { get; set; }
```

After sometime I could not find anything online to describe it, why?

## EDIT 1

What is Oalton? it is a tool for Parsing and Utilities for Command Line Tools in .Net
https://jasperfx.github.io/oakton/

Comment: I’m so confused did you ask a question and then answer yourself?

Comment: @MickyD I struggled to find a solution that's why I have added the Q&A here. Thanks for your comment. I have added the code and the link for Oakton.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

I found that flags should end with `Flag` in their property name while arguments shouldn't.

`OneFlag` and `TwoFlag` two will be recognised as flags while flag `Three` will be recognised as an argument. Because, the last one doesn't end with `Flag` in the property name. So final solution will be:

```
[FlagAlias("o", true)]
[Description("Flag One")]
[Required]
public string OneFlag { get; set; }

[FlagAlias("t", true)]
[Description("Flag Two")]
[Required]
public string TwoFlag { get; set; }

[FlagAlias("r", true)]
[Description("Flag Three")]
[Required]
public string ThreeFlag { get; set; }
```